# Is possible to get elements from XML using Notepad++ Regex?

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have an XML with different `Item`'s which may contain the attribute `Setting` named `SerialNumber`. Im trying to get all the item names followed with the serial number.

My approch is using Notepad++ Regex, to get the name of the `Item` and the value of the attribute `Setting` named `SerialNumber`something like this:

> Sender0;3990  Sender3;4444  Sender4;7774

But trying it the only thing i can get is that notepad++ selects all the text... My fast approach was something like this:

```
^<Item Name="(.*)" Category=".*<Setting Name="SerialNumber">(.*)</Setting>.*</Item>
```

And replace:

```
(\1);(\2)
```

The XML:

```
    <Item Name="Sender0" Category="" ClassName="Cars" Schedule="" Enabled="true">
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting Name="SerialNumber">3990</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Sender1" Category="" ClassName="Cars" Schedule="" Enabled="true">
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Sender2" Category="" ClassName="Cars" Schedule="" Enabled="true">
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Sender3" Category="" ClassName="Cars" Schedule="" Enabled="true">
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting Name="SerialNumber">4444</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Sender4" Category="" ClassName="Cars" Schedule="" Enabled="true">
     <Setting>...</Setting>
     <Setting Name="SerialNumber">7774</Setting>
     <Setting>...</Setting>
    </Item>
```

Hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: Regex + XML = **evil evil evil** ... not my downvote, but regex in NPP is not the best too to use here.  Look into using an XML parser.

Comment: Tim is right. What other technologies can you use? For example, would Powershell be an option?

Comment: The idea is to make it work with notepad++ using Regex, i know i can make it with Java or other ways... But the point is understand why my regex isn't working as i expect, sorry for the incovenience. And thanks for answer you both.

Comment: Regex isn't working because regex cannot be used with XML. Use one of the tools that have been made for XML processing, they exist for a reason.

Comment: I see its a really bad example to use with notepad++ regex

Comment: Indeed, yes. If processing this file is your task, I suggest Powershell because that approach has zero external dependencies in Windows. If you just chose it as a way to learn regex, I suggest working with something other than XML.

Comment: [Obligatory link about the futility of trying to parse X/HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576)

Comment: Ken if you post it as an answer i will put it as a accepted one. This is something that has to be present if another one falls into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regex is [viable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/7500028) for this. Unless you are missing some details on the question.

Try with this:

Search: `\s*<Item\s*Name="([^"]+)"[^>]+>(?:\s*<Setting>.*?<\/Setting>)*(?:\s*<Setting Name="SerialNumber">(.*?)<\/Setting>)?(?:\s*<Setting>.*?<\/Setting>)*\s*<\/Item>`

Replace by: `(?2\1;\2 )`

In notepadd++, the output of your given input would be: `Sender0;3990 Sender3;4444 Sender4;7774`

NOTE: Do **not** use `. matches new line` option. Also, use `match case` if you need so.

**Explanation:**

```
\s*                  # 0 or more spaces (space, tab, new line...)
<Item                # Literal '<item'
    \s*              
    Name="           # Literal 'Name="'
        ([^"]+)      # Any non (") character repeated one or more times
                     #   stored on the first capturing group
    "                # Literal "
    [^>]+            # Any non (>) character repeated one or more
>                    # Literal >
# After searching for Item Name, there must exists its serial number.
# The serialNumber may be sorrounded by other settings, so We will search:
# perhapsSomeSettings + serialNumber + perhapsSomeSettings
# so that we will be able to find (if exists) the serial number wether it
# is placed as the first, last or middle tag.
(?:     # group
    \s*
    <Setting>.*?<\/Setting>
)*      # repeat 0 or more
(?:     # This 'setting' group will have the serial number
    \s*
    <Setting Name="SerialNumber">
    (.*?)    # We capture the data (second capturing group)
    <\/Setting>
)?     # Optional
(?:    
    \s*
    <Setting>
        .*?
    <\/Setting>
)*
\s*
<\/Item>
```

Please, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) about greedy/lazy quantifiers.

For the replacement we use `(?2\1;\2 )`

`(?2)` is special syntax in notepadd++ (boost) regexes. It means that if the second capturing group exists, then what's inside is applied. So in our case `(?2\1;\2 )` if the second capturing group exists our replacement will be first capturing group (name), `;` and second capturing group (serialNumber)

Comment: If you can explain a little bit your regex i'll be extremely grateful, for learning purposes and prevent people like me to fall in this kind of questions :)

Comment: Sure, @Ralsho. I edited my answert to add the explanation.